# Query multiple columns and combine with column header when sorting

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I have inventory data organized like this:

[image]

And am trying to write a query that will sort it like this:

[image]

I can get the data to combine and sort from multiple columns, but I can't figure out how to add the size header to the sort, so I have no way of knowing what size each item is.

[Sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JOWe2F8raEpI1P3J5OuweNkTmDS0hWEuo0OLNfsxoT4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B3:D="",,A3:A&"×"&B2:D2&"×"&B3:D)), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I wrapped the QUERY in a SORT to get my final result, which works. I wish I understood more about what was going on in the ELSE portion of the IF statement.

Comment: @user15250594 just a simple combination with unique symbol and then simple split removing the unique symbol from final output